# Is there a way I can setup my default view of Shading or Sculpting window?

Tags: customization

Is there a possibility to change my default view of let's say Shading window in Blender, so that I don't have to adjust it in every project (Size of the windows, types of the windows etc)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is

Adjust everything the way you want it to be when opening Blender

Then go to

File --> Defaults --> Save startup file

[image]

You can find the startup file in this relative path, in case, you are changing your pc and is too lazy to adjust it once again

**C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\BlenderVersion\config\startup.blend**